# Python OpenCV append matches' center x, y coordinates in tuples

Tags: python, opencv

I have this simple opencv template matching function written in Python.

image: [image]

template: [image]

```
def find(object, sensitivity):
    screen = "tool.png"

    screen_read = cv2.imread(screen)
    screen_gray = cv2.cvtColor(screen_read, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    obj = cv2.imread(object, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    w, h = obj.shape[::-1]

    location = np.where(cv2.matchTemplate(screen_gray, obj, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED) >= sensitivity)
    positions = []
    for xy in zip(*location[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(screen_read, xy, (xy[0] + w, xy[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 1)
        x = random(xy[0], (xy[0] + w) - 2)
        y = random(xy[1], (xy[1] + h) - 2)
        print(x, y)
        positions.append(str(x) + ", " + str(y))
    #cv2.imshow("Test", screen_read)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)


find("enemylogo.png", 0.90)
```

It will find all the templates correctly, as shown here: [image]

However, my goal here is to pass the center coordinate to be used in loop, outside the function. For this, I need to store the x, y coordinates in an array (positions), as tuples.

However, I'm not getting desired results, it's adding too many tuples instead of only 2.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
for x in find("enemylogo.png", 0.90):
    click(x) #x would be the coordinate of every template matched.
```

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: You need to limit the good matches to some minimum distance threshold from each other. Slight shifts of the template near a local peak may still be higher than your threshold. I often mask out a region of the image at the match point in the correlation surface image, then find the next match rather than trying to get all matches.

Comment: Is there any example, please?

Comment: The only example I have is an ImageMagick script that I wrote. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/maxima/index.php. I have not seen that done in Python/OpenCV. Perhaps there are other methods. But you can certainly do it in OpenCV. You just save the correlation surface image from the matchTemplate. Then find the highest value. Then draw a black circle or rectangle at that location of some minimum size that will mask the local peak below your threshold. The repeat the search in the modified correlation surface image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `location = np.where....` will give you a lot of matches, and many of them will be right next to each other. Another technique is to recursively use [minMaxLoc](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab473bf2eb6d14ff97e89b355dac20707). This function will only give you the best result. But if you overwrite the best match with zeros on the first pass through, the second pass will find another match.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def find_templates(obj, sensitivity):

    image = cv2.imread('tool.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR )
    template = cv2.imread(obj, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    h, w = template.shape[:2]

    print('h', h, 'w', w)

    method = cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED

    threshold = 0.90

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, method)
    res_h, res_w = res.shape[:2]

    # fake out max_val for first run through loop
    max_val = 1
    centers = []
    while max_val > sensitivity:
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
        if max_val > sensitivity:
            centers.append( (max_loc[0] + w//2, max_loc[1] + h//2) )

            x1 = max(max_loc[0] - w//2, 0)
            y1 = max(max_loc[1] - h//2, 0)

            x2 = min(max_loc[0] + w//2, res_w)
            y2 = min(max_loc[1] + h//2, res_h)

            res[y1:y2, x1:x2] = 0

            image = cv2.rectangle(image,(max_loc[0],max_loc[1]), (max_loc[0]+w+1, max_loc[1]+h+1), (0,255,0) )

    print(centers)

    cv2.imwrite('output.png', image)

find_templates("enemy_logo.png", 0.90)
```

which gives

```
[(52, 52), (169, 52)]
```

[image]